# position of the end of a rotating arrow

Tags: javascript, math

I have an arrow that rotates. How can I calculate the position of the end/bottom  of it relative to its angle/rotation ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you need is called [Polar to Cartesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates). 
You need to know 2 things:

- Angle of rotation
- The length of the arrow

Then you can apply this formula to get your x,y position:

```
x = r * cosθ, 
y = r * sinθ
```

Where `r = length of arrow` and `θ = the angle of rotation`.

EDIT: When using this, have in mind that the start of the arrow is considered the origin point `(0,0)`.

Comment: Thanks, so I already have an object that is located on the middle of the arrow, now i need to edit the position of the object somehow to be at the end of the arrow regarding to arrow's rotation. i tried `object.x * (r * cosθ), object.y * (r * sinθ)` && `object.x + (r * cosθ), object.y + (r * sinθ)`, but those didn't work. can you help me with that?

Comment: Where is center of rotation? You can find arrow coordinates against rotation center using given formula, then add position of rot. conter to get global coordinates.

Comment: @adamwest You need to set the object.x to r * cosθ and object.y to r * sinθ.

Comment: @ΧρήστοςΚαρανίκας nvm, It works fine now, i had forgotten to convert degree to radian, to get the global position this works:`object.x + (r * cosθ), object.y + (r * sinθ)` thank you very much